# Linux: when mv fails, is the original file still intact?

Tags: linux, mv

I used the mv command on a file then this message appeared:

```
mv 'file.tar': Disk quota exceeded
```

but now there is a file.tar in both the new location and the old location. They're different sizes and I have no idea what the size of the original file was. (There are a lotttt of files in this tarball)

Can I just delete the file that failed to get moved or will I lose part of my original data if I do that?

Comment: Please elaborate on the source and destination filesystems. Are they the same filesystem?

Comment: If you performed `mv A B` and the operation failed, you can safely remove `B`.  The file `A` is removed only upon successful move to the alternate location.  (To elaborate, `A` is still the original file while `B` is likely to be a part of it.)

Comment: @devnull Does this mean it's exactly the same to do `cp -r A B && rm A` (due to nature of the AND operator)? Or is there some subtle difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Unix/Linux `mv(1)`-es a file, if source and destination are on the same filesystem, it is just a rename. This can't give an "out of space" message (at least not AFAICS). When moving a file between filesystems (different partitions or disks), what is done is to copy the source to the destination, and when the operation suceeds, the source is deleted. During the copying the destination filesystem can run out of space, and the source won't be deleted. It is strange that the (partial) destination stays in your case, in my experience `mv` cleans that up (but it's been a while...). In this case the user to which the target file belongs is running out of allowed disk space.